# How to deploy bat file within remote dileserver through jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server

I have installed Jenkins at 1.1.1.01 Ipaddress, and a bat file does exist at remote fileserver 1.1.1.02 Ipaddress (that may differ by user, because I will give Ipaddress as a parameter).

Can I deploy that bat file through Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to check, independently of Jenkins, if you can access 1.1.1.02 (or any other remote server IPs) from `1.1.1.01`, assuming `1.1.1.01` is the server executing your job.

If, from `1.1.1.01`, you can SSH for instance to `1.1.1.02`, or `scp 1.1.1.02`, then you can copy a file (like your bat file), from `1.1.1.01` to `1.1.1.02` or vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..  So I need to connect remote server by using SSH or SCP and then can deploy bat file at there.... Right?

Comment: @Momo Yes, the idea is: do it manually. Once that is working, your Jenkins agent (if running with the same user) will be able to replicate the command you did to deploy the bat file there.